# Make javascript ip address regex reject the digit 0

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^(?:(25(?!0)[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$
```

Trouble figuring out how to make this reject the values:

```
0.x.x.x
0.0.0.0
0.x.x.0
```

Comment: For what its worth, I think a regex *only* method(even if possible) to solve this problem would be too complex. Better break it down to conditions and eliminate the invalid ones.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a LOT easier to maintain to split the string on periods and validate each number?

Comment: Also, if 0.x.x.x is rejected, then 0.0.0.0 and 0.x.x.0 are implicitely also rejected

Comment: If you mean not only zeroes between the dots perhaps `^(?![0-9.]*\b0{1,3}\b).*` https://regex101.com/r/yaRqEP/1 and replace the .* with matching an ip number

Answer (score 0):

The last `[0-9]` term should be `[1-9]`.

Also, to require a period between the numeric components of the address, the period `.` should escaped: `\.` And if you do not intend to prohibit `250` as a component, `25(?!0)` should just be `25`.

For example:

```
^(?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$
```